# matplotlib - removing time gaps in time-series data plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have a set of data that matches time values against another value (for example, elevation). I'm currently plotting this in `matplotlib`, and it looks something like this:

[image: Example of plot.]

As can be seen, there are big 'gaps' in the data, with lines connecting between them, because the times plotted are not right next to each other.

My code looks like this (I do not have have `pandas`):

```
time_sorted_list = sorted(
    unsorted_value_list, key=lambda x: x.time
)

elev = [i.elev for i in time_sorted_list]

time = [i.time for i in time_sorted_list]

...(creating elev_plot figure)

elev_plot.plot(time, elev)

elev_plot.grid()
plot.show()
```

How can I set up `matplotlib` to remove these large gaps in time, such that all values sit close to each other? I don't want to remove time altogether - knowing when each elevation value occurs is important.

**Example data:**

Elevations:

```
[7.061637017210896, 8.62634035986128, 9.449231409579046, 9.449245213599722, 11.183401391828983, 11.183478912151985, 12.097695062804538, 14.032121063226736, 19.53103255309029, 20.132430448781705, 22.61562154333468, 23.892538058003574, 25.174568988146742, 25.81347252259264, 27.07766665010065, 28.301824218809962, 29.4560748154805, 30.51425894250495, 31.44003996067941, 32.19935454662037, 32.75797351858856, 33.09230892539046, 33.185638377860386, 32.64289077682021, 32.64282073446187, 32.03439364065985, 32.03432718356379, 31.235743890788736, 30.278072995085186, 29.198208966807904, 28.02762496428912, 25.534718034319297, 24.259335234095236, 22.987561974637945, 21.733969026630948, 20.50551578656278, 19.30698140187512, 18.145822000390414, 17.021157410685678, 14.89032761900031, 13.881534452146786, 12.910228441720443, 11.9735858799619, 10.20078824064575, 8.548230021876677, 7.7622314951825935, 7.002108526108933, 6.2652418436101245, 5.550265750342097, 4.180538242033181, 3.523953356314147, 10.468976986513358, 10.826799614265274, 11.548804997129018, 15.198784031309774, 15.913277577899912, 16.609161706884624, 18.52422058507705, 19.077032064883326, 19.57286148977654, 20.002244208317894, 20.91143576667658, 20.91127829131031, 20.911272488234292, 20.817089892791472, 20.630717861747748, 20.630698531303153, 20.35705893695184, 20.357030796826844, 20.001375885553323, 19.571700419702164, 19.075697249423904, 17.921110661414083, 15.911217262744842, 15.197579232135709, 14.472858366158526, 13.740784521720999, 13.007405649336956]
```

Time (stored as datetime):

```
['08/26/2021, 08:28:28', '08/26/2021, 08:28:48', '08/26/2021, 08:28:58', '08/26/2021, 08:28:58', '08/26/2021, 08:29:18', '08/26/2021, 08:29:18', '08/26/2021, 08:29:28', '08/26/2021, 08:29:48', '08/26/2021, 08:30:38', '08/26/2021, 08:30:43', '08/26/2021, 08:31:03', '08/26/2021, 08:31:13', '08/26/2021, 08:31:23', '08/26/2021, 08:31:28', '08/26/2021, 08:31:38', '08/26/2021, 08:31:48', '08/26/2021, 08:31:58', '08/26/2021, 08:32:08', '08/26/2021, 08:32:18', '08/26/2021, 08:32:28', '08/26/2021, 08:32:38', '08/26/2021, 08:32:48', '08/26/2021, 08:32:58', '08/26/2021, 08:33:18', '08/26/2021, 08:33:18', '08/26/2021, 08:33:28', '08/26/2021, 08:33:28', '08/26/2021, 08:33:38', '08/26/2021, 08:33:48', '08/26/2021, 08:33:58', '08/26/2021, 08:34:08', '08/26/2021, 08:34:28', '08/26/2021, 08:34:38', '08/26/2021, 08:34:48', '08/26/2021, 08:34:58', '08/26/2021, 08:35:08', '08/26/2021, 08:35:18', '08/26/2021, 08:35:28', '08/26/2021, 08:35:38', '08/26/2021, 08:35:58', '08/26/2021, 08:36:08', '08/26/2021, 08:36:18', '08/26/2021, 08:36:28', '08/26/2021, 08:36:48', '08/26/2021, 08:37:08', '08/26/2021, 08:37:18', '08/26/2021, 08:37:28', '08/26/2021, 08:37:38', '08/26/2021, 08:37:48', '08/26/2021, 08:38:08', '08/26/2021, 08:38:18', '08/26/2021, 10:11:00', '08/26/2021, 10:11:05', '08/26/2021, 10:11:15', '08/26/2021, 10:12:05', '08/26/2021, 10:12:15', '08/26/2021, 10:12:25', '08/26/2021, 10:12:55', '08/26/2021, 10:13:05', '08/26/2021, 10:13:15', '08/26/2021, 10:13:25', '08/26/2021, 10:14:05', '08/26/2021, 10:14:15', '08/26/2021, 10:14:15', '08/26/2021, 10:14:25', '08/26/2021, 10:14:35', '08/26/2021, 10:14:35', '08/26/2021, 10:14:45', '08/26/2021, 10:14:45', '08/26/2021, 10:14:55', '08/26/2021, 10:15:05', '08/26/2021, 10:15:15', '08/26/2021, 10:15:35', '08/26/2021, 10:16:05', '08/26/2021, 10:16:15', '08/26/2021, 10:16:25', '08/26/2021, 10:16:35', '08/26/2021, 10:16:45']
```

Comment: please provide a minimal example with data as text

Comment: @mozway example data has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to remove the large gaps between the peaks?

##### updated answer using pandas

I broke down the steps in independent columns for you to see the logic

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'elev': elev})
df['time']   = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])         
df['delta']  = df['time'].diff()              # diff from previous time
df['gap']    = df['delta'].dt.seconds.gt(100) # gap = diff > 100 seconds
df['group']  = df['gap'].cumsum()             # make groups


groups = df.groupby('group')
f, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=len(groups), sharey=True)
for i, g in groups:
    ax[i].plot(g['time'], g['elev'])
    start = g['time'].iloc[0].time()
    stop = g['time'].iloc[-1].time()
    ax[i].set_title(f'group {i+1}\n({start}--{stop})')
```

output:

[image: plot without gaps]

##### old answer

Original data:

```
from datetime import datetime
elev = [7.061637017210896, 8.62634035986128, 9.449231409579046, 9.449245213599722, 11.183401391828983, 11.183478912151985, 12.097695062804538, 14.032121063226736, 19.53103255309029, 20.132430448781705, 22.61562154333468, 23.892538058003574, 25.174568988146742, 25.81347252259264, 27.07766665010065, 28.301824218809962, 29.4560748154805, 30.51425894250495, 31.44003996067941, 32.19935454662037, 32.75797351858856, 33.09230892539046, 33.185638377860386, 32.64289077682021, 32.64282073446187, 32.03439364065985, 32.03432718356379, 31.235743890788736, 30.278072995085186, 29.198208966807904, 28.02762496428912, 25.534718034319297, 24.259335234095236, 22.987561974637945, 21.733969026630948, 20.50551578656278, 19.30698140187512, 18.145822000390414, 17.021157410685678, 14.89032761900031, 13.881534452146786, 12.910228441720443, 11.9735858799619, 10.20078824064575, 8.548230021876677, 7.7622314951825935, 7.002108526108933, 6.2652418436101245, 5.550265750342097, 4.180538242033181, 3.523953356314147, 10.468976986513358, 10.826799614265274, 11.548804997129018, 15.198784031309774, 15.913277577899912, 16.609161706884624, 18.52422058507705, 19.077032064883326, 19.57286148977654, 20.002244208317894, 20.91143576667658, 20.91127829131031, 20.911272488234292, 20.817089892791472, 20.630717861747748, 20.630698531303153, 20.35705893695184, 20.357030796826844, 20.001375885553323, 19.571700419702164, 19.075697249423904, 17.921110661414083, 15.911217262744842, 15.197579232135709, 14.472858366158526, 13.740784521720999, 13.007405649336956]
time = ['08/26/2021, 08:28:28', '08/26/2021, 08:28:48', '08/26/2021, 08:28:58', '08/26/2021, 08:28:58', '08/26/2021, 08:29:18', '08/26/2021, 08:29:18', '08/26/2021, 08:29:28', '08/26/2021, 08:29:48', '08/26/2021, 08:30:38', '08/26/2021, 08:30:43', '08/26/2021, 08:31:03', '08/26/2021, 08:31:13', '08/26/2021, 08:31:23', '08/26/2021, 08:31:28', '08/26/2021, 08:31:38', '08/26/2021, 08:31:48', '08/26/2021, 08:31:58', '08/26/2021, 08:32:08', '08/26/2021, 08:32:18', '08/26/2021, 08:32:28', '08/26/2021, 08:32:38', '08/26/2021, 08:32:48', '08/26/2021, 08:32:58', '08/26/2021, 08:33:18', '08/26/2021, 08:33:18', '08/26/2021, 08:33:28', '08/26/2021, 08:33:28', '08/26/2021, 08:33:38', '08/26/2021, 08:33:48', '08/26/2021, 08:33:58', '08/26/2021, 08:34:08', '08/26/2021, 08:34:28', '08/26/2021, 08:34:38', '08/26/2021, 08:34:48', '08/26/2021, 08:34:58', '08/26/2021, 08:35:08', '08/26/2021, 08:35:18', '08/26/2021, 08:35:28', '08/26/2021, 08:35:38', '08/26/2021, 08:35:58', '08/26/2021, 08:36:08', '08/26/2021, 08:36:18', '08/26/2021, 08:36:28', '08/26/2021, 08:36:48', '08/26/2021, 08:37:08', '08/26/2021, 08:37:18', '08/26/2021, 08:37:28', '08/26/2021, 08:37:38', '08/26/2021, 08:37:48', '08/26/2021, 08:38:08', '08/26/2021, 08:38:18', '08/26/2021, 10:11:00', '08/26/2021, 10:11:05', '08/26/2021, 10:11:15', '08/26/2021, 10:12:05', '08/26/2021, 10:12:15', '08/26/2021, 10:12:25', '08/26/2021, 10:12:55', '08/26/2021, 10:13:05', '08/26/2021, 10:13:15', '08/26/2021, 10:13:25', '08/26/2021, 10:14:05', '08/26/2021, 10:14:15', '08/26/2021, 10:14:15', '08/26/2021, 10:14:25', '08/26/2021, 10:14:35', '08/26/2021, 10:14:35', '08/26/2021, 10:14:45', '08/26/2021, 10:14:45', '08/26/2021, 10:14:55', '08/26/2021, 10:15:05', '08/26/2021, 10:15:15', '08/26/2021, 10:15:35', '08/26/2021, 10:16:05', '08/26/2021, 10:16:15', '08/26/2021, 10:16:25', '08/26/2021, 10:16:35', '08/26/2021, 10:16:45']
time = [datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S') for t in time]
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(time, elev, marker='.')
```

[image: original data]

The issue is that the points are not evenly spaced:

```
   interval  count
0      10.0     50
1      20.0     11
2       0.0      7
3       5.0      3
4      50.0      2
5      30.0      2
6      40.0      1
7    5562.0      1
```

A simple solution is to plot without keeping the time information, with a fixed step:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(range(len(elev)), elev, marker='.')
```

[image: fixed step]

There are other ways, but it is more complicated, so make your requirements explicit if the quick solution does not work for you.

Comment: well yeah, plotting against a numeric range would remove the long stretches, but if this is really what OP wants, it's totally misrepresenting the data.

Comment: @tdy thus my comment at the end. But from experience, sometimes you do not care about the time and rather want to see the point to point evolution.

Comment: Unfortunately I still want to know what the time is per group of data as the gap between points (not the large ones, I mean between elevation values) is still important

Comment: @jos do you really have not to use pandas?

Comment: @mozway If I were to use Pandas, how could I remove the gaps?

Comment: @jos I updated the answer with a pandas alternative (you could do it without pandas, but it's just much more work)

Comment: Right now I am using the brokenaxes library to somewhat sidestep multiple plots, but this is also a very good solution. Thank you!